# Experiential Code Review for java

Tags: java

Please refer below scenarios for details of my question

Scenario 1:
I implemented a simple XML tag modification logic wherein I had to update various XML tags. During code review, an experienced java guy informs that this is a good candidate to use velocity template in java.

Scenarion 2:
I implemented a jdbc module to connect to multiple database, execute queries and retrieve output. During code review, an experienced Java guys informs that this is a good candidate to use AbstractRoutingDataSource interface wherein you can associate key to each data source and access it accordingly using spring framework.

How do I know that such things already exists in java which I get to know during code review. Static code review/coverage tools will not provide me such valuable experiential code review feedback.

I am from C#, VB.net background and now working on java for past 1 year and I find java to be an excellent programming language with lots of things already in place. We just need to find what we want to find and accordingly learn and integrate it.

So, my question is :
How do I know such things already exists and how do I search for such things which I am not aware of?

Comment: a) post your stuff on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ b) use Google :-)

Comment: read advanced books about design patterns and specific topics (advanced gui-engineeringe etc.) you won't learn those techniques by beginners guides, and you can learn lots of techniques by understanding design patterns so you "see them" while writing code.

Comment: Google gives everything if we know what to search. Here, knowing what to search is a challenge. Searching for the text "java jdbc best practices for connecting to multiple data source" in google, does not show info on AbstractRoutingDataSource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say you can't always. Even Google doesn't help if you don't know what to look for or don't even get the idea to look for something because you already have a working solution.

In the end it's all experience and you've only been doing Java for a year. In your scenarios you gained experience and next time you will do it that way right away. Code reviews are not only for making the code better. They also are for teaching/learning from other programmers with different knowledge and experience. To even further encourage this use pair programming with frequently rotating pairs.